# how to eliminate texture stretching in greybox levels

Tags: texturing, uv

I am using blender to try and mock up some greybox levels to be used in UE4 with megascans. when I make the anything using the plane in blender no matter how i edit it the scaling is of once i put a texture on it in UE4. it is to stretched out one way or the other and i cant seem to figure it out. I have tried selecting the whole plane and setting the scale and using uv smart unwrap. [image: Checkered boxes stretched to rectangles]

[image: Added plane then grabbed edges in edit mode on the x axsis]

[image: Result]

Comment: I don't know UE4, but in blender you can set reset the transformation with CONTROL+A (choose "scale").
See the before and after screenshot.
before: https://i.imgur.com/gi4MFQp.png
after: https://i.imgur.com/cLjPaGc.png

Comment: Use more subdivisions. Large faces are prone to give you UV mapping errors.

Comment: I subdivided and set the scale with no luck. how do i get to the uv mapping section that shows where my model is stretching?